# Show that there is a matrix $L$ such that $A + L$ has eigenvalue $\mu$ and eigenvector $x$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a matrix, $v$ be a unit vector, $\mu$
be a scalar, and $r = Av — \mu v$. I want to show that there is a matrix $L$ with $||L||_F=||r||_2$ such that $A + L$ has eigenvalue $\mu$ and eigenvector $x$.

The only thing that occurs to me is to start operations with the norms, but I have not reached anything

Could someone give me a hint?

Comment: If $A + L$ has eigenvalue $\mu$ and eigenvector $x$, we have $(A + L)x = Ax + L x = \mu x$, implying $Ax - \mu x = - Lx$. Dividing by $\| x \|$ gives $Av - \mu v = - L v$. Since $v := \frac{x}{\| x \|}$ is a unit vector, by assumption we have $r = - L v$. Furthermore, $$\| r \|_2 = \| - L v \|_2 \le \| - L \|_{F} \| v \| = \| -L \|_{F} \cdot 1 = \| L \|_F.$$

Comment: Since the well-known inequality for the Frobenius norm used above is proven with Cauchy-Schwarz, equality holds if every row of $L$ is linearly independent to $v$.

Comment: @Viktor Glombik  But how i get the equality of the norms?

Comment: "equality holds if every row of $L$ is linearly independent to $v$."